# subtract element from number if element satisfies if condition numpy

Tags: python, numpy

say I have array `a=np.random.randn(4,2)` and I want to subtract each negative element from 100.
if I want to subtract 100 from each element then I would use `a[(a<0)] -=100.` but what if I want to subtract each element from 100.  How can I do it without looping through each element?

Comment: `a[a < 0] = 100 - a[a < 0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the temporary array in @Akiiino's solution by using the `out` and `where` arguments of `np.ufunc`s:

```
np.subtract(100, a, out=a, where=a<0)
```

In general, the meaning of `ufunc(a, b, out, where)` is roughly:

```
out[where] = ufunc(a[where], b[where])
```

Comparing the speed:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: a = np.random.randn(10000, 2)
In [3]: b = a.copy()  # so the that boolean mask doesn't change

In [4]: %timeit a[b < 0] = 100 - a[b < 0]
307 µs ± 1.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit np.subtract(100, a, out=a, where=b < 0)
260 µs ± 39.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

We see that there's a ~15% speed boost here

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same idea:

```
a[a<0] = 100 - a[a<0]
```